# other subnet CANNOT resolve internal host name but can resovle internet host name

Tags: bind

Pls help. I just setup a Bind9 in Ubuntu 20.4 server(192.168.1.100). I have 3 subnet in the network. 192.168.0.0/23, 192.168.33.0/24 and 192.168.88.0/24.

In 192.168.0.0/23 network, I can resolve Internet Host name and Internal host name without problem.

But in 192.168.33.0/24 and 192.168.88.0/24 netowork, I can resolve the Internet Host name such [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). But I cannot resolve the right IP for the internal host. When I try to resovle an internal host. It will return the IP 208.91.112.55.

Anyone knows what is the problem?[options file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjCQ4.png)[local file[zone file[ping result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U63YV.png)